# Visual Studio 2015 apache cordova

Tags: android, cordova, visual-studio-2015

I have an app that uses WebSQL transactions to create a table, insert data, and retrieve information from a database.

The app works fine on the Ripple Nexus (Galaxy) but not on the device (Galaxy Note 5) nor the emulator. The UI is there: text boxes, labels, buttons, etc. However, according to my notice, the operations on the database are not performed.

What can I do?

Answer (score 0):

There are not enough details here to tell what is going on and no code samples.  Note that ripple is using http and your app on the device is probably using a non http:// calling location.  Another possible issue is that on your machine there is web connectivity to a local http endpoint and on the device the end point would not be available unless it is public on the internet / available to the device.

Answer (score 0):

Here is sample of my code, open database and populate data tables:

```
document.addEventListener('deviceready', onDeviceReady.bind(this), false);
var db = openDatabase('DUTIESDB', '1.0', 'Test DB', 2 * 1024 * 1024);
db.transaction(function (tx) {
    tx.executeSql("DROP TABLE DUTIES", []);
    tx.executeSql("DROP TABLE SDUTIES", []);
    tx.executeSql('CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS DUTIES (id, name, date, time, course, room)');
    tx.executeSql('CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS SDUTIES (id, name, date, time, course, room, invg)');
});

PupulateSupTable();

function PopulateSupTable() {
    var xmlhttp = new XMLHttpRequest();
    var url = "/scripts/SupDuties.txt";

    xmlhttp.onreadystatechange = function () {
        if (xmlhttp.readyState == 4 && xmlhttp.status == 200) {
            var myArr = JSON.parse(xmlhttp.responseText);
            db.transaction(
                function (tx) {
                    var k, sql = 'INSERT INTO SDUTIES (id, name, date, time, course, room, invg) VALUES (?,?,?,?,?,?,?)';
                    for (k = 0; k < myArr.length; k++) {
                        tx.executeSql(sql, [myArr[k].ID, myArr[k].Name, myArr[k].Date, myArr[k].Time, myArr[k].Course, myArr[k].Room, myArr[k].Invigilator]);
                    }
                }
            );
        }
    };
    xmlhttp.open("GET", url, true);
    xmlhttp.send();
}
```

Comment: If webSQL is having trouble connecting to the internet, it seems that you need to make sure your CSP is allowing your emulator/device to reach the internet. Adjust the CSP meta tag in the <head> section of index.html